# Using ConvertToText() Method For convert a word table to text

Tags: c#, ms-word

I use microsoft.office.interop.word and I want to use ConvertToText method to convert a word table to text but I can't send Separator parameter.
This is my code:

```
foreach (Table item in doc.Tables)
{
    if (item.Rows.Count==1 && item.Columns.Count==1)
    {
        item.Tables[0].ConvertToText(Separator: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByParagraphs, NestedTables: false);
    }
}
```